# Только числа в maskedTextBox

Tags: .net, winforms, c++

Как разрешить ввод в maskedTextBox только целые числа? Чтобы можно было воспользоваться backspace, нельзя пробелом и точками с запятыми?  Или просто в textbox.

Managed C++.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Используйте [формат](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.forms.maskedtextbox.mask.aspx) маски

> 0 - Цифра, необходимый символ. Для этого элемента допускается любая одиночная цифра от 0 до 9.

```
mtb.Mask = "000";
```

Эта маска разрешит ввод целых чисел от 000 - до 999.

Answer (score 0):

Так прочтите документацию про этот компонент. Вот [тут](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.maskedtextbox.mask.aspx) хотя бы.